# Can i return different objects in views of same action method in Http get and Http Post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, http-post

I want to return an object on HTTPGet method and different object in HTTPPost method of the same action method in the controller, but i dont know what to write in the view, which model to get.
Here is the controller code , i have been trying

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var intSrNo = Convert.ToInt64(TempData["sr_no"]);
            MEntities obj_entity = new MEntities();
            UDP_get_a_Result obj_proc = obj_entity.UDP_get_a(intSrNo).SingleOrDefault(); 
             return View(obj_proc);
        } 

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Table_a obj_a)
        {           
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Table_a.AddObject(obj_a);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }
            return View(obj_a);
        }
```

i'm confused which model to write in view.(Table_a or UDP_get_a_Result) and i want both HttpGet to show values when the page is loaded and HttpPost when the submit is clicked.

View

```
@model ABC.models.Table_a           
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A view can only be strongly typed to a single class. You cannot have different controller actions returning the same view and passing different models to this view. You could use view models: define a class which will hold all the information necessary for this view and then have your controller actions fill this view models and pass it to this view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work to have the view typed to some base class (object) and then cast the model to whatever you needed it to be based on get/post.  I wouldn't want to maintain it tho. :-D